# Using selenium to write to Chrome console

Tags: python, selenium

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Selenium to write to the Chrome console with python. I do not mean by using send_keys to press F12 and open the console then send more keys to write. If this isn't possible, are they any libraries or APIs that would let me do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the problem with another view, try to use `browser.execute_script` and pass `console.log("whatever you want to write in the console")` , this will print that sentence in the console

You can of course change it to your own needs but you get the idea